# rewrite urls with optional parameters and avoid confusion

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

assuming I have these 5 urls (with parameters) and want to create url rewrite for each of them.
these URLs are possible results of a search form.
(the search by form is done with 3 filters which are optional : speciality, region, city)

```
search.php?speciality=cardiologist&region=my_region&city=my_city
doctor/cardiologist/my_region/my_city

search.php?speciality=cardiologist&region=my_region
doctor/cardiologist/my_region

search.php?speciality=cardiologist
doctor/cardiologist

search.php?region=my_region&city=my_city
doctor/my_region/my_city

search.php?region=my_region
doctor/my_region
```

how would I be able to use htaccess/regex rewrite rules to manage these urls and avoid confusion

I tried this but I think that it creates confusion so it doesn't work well (I'm begginer in regex)

```
RewriteRule ^doctor/([a-zA-Z\-]+) search.php?speciality=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^doctor/([a-zA-Z\-]+) search.php?region=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^doctor/([a-zA-Z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z\-]+) search.php?speciality=$1&region=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^doctor/([a-zA-Z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z\-]+) search.php?region=$1&city=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^doctor/([a-zA-Z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z\-]+) search.php?speciality=$1&region=$2&city=$3 [L]
```

what solutions do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> search.php?speciality=cardiologist&region=my_region&city=my_city
> doctor/cardiologist/my_region/my_city
> ```

You can't resolve this ambiguity in `.htaccess`/mod_rewrite if `speciality`, `region` and `city` are all independently optional and entirely variable.

The query string resolves this ambiguity by including a parameter name. If you remove the identifying "name" (as you are doing in the URL-path) it's entirely ambiguous.

Just from a human-readable stand point, how would *you* know what the following URLs represent?

- `doctor/foo/bar`
- `doctor/baz/qux`

If all values of `speciality`, `region` and `city` are unique in your application then you can potentially resolve this ambiguity in your PHP script by looking up the values in your DB to determine which value is the `speciality`, `region` or `city`. But this puts a significant overhead on your application as you are having to perform several additional DB lookups. And if they are not unique (now or in the future) then this problem is impossible to resolve.

You need *something* in the URL-path that identifies each value: `speciality`, `region` or `city`. For example:

- `doctor/s-cardiologist/r-my_region/c-my_city`
- `doctor/r-my_region/c-my_city`
- `doctor/s/my_speciality/r/my_region/c/my_city`
- `doctor/r/my_region/c/my_city`

Or use a placeholder when a value is not available:

- `doctor/my-speciality/my-region/my-city`
- `doctor/none/my-region/my-city`
- `doctor/none/none/my-city`

Although are these solutions any better than the original query string?

Comment: Yees ! it works with this solution doctor/s-cardiologist/r-my_region/c-my_city, ok it's less attractive than doctor/cardiologist/my_region/my_city but it's still seo/ux friendly
thank you very much MrWhite (sorry I didn't understand what did you mean by your question )

Comment: @narseoh Well, it is debatable whether `doctor/s-cardiologist/r-my_region/c-my_city` is really any better than `search.php?speciality=cardiologist&region=my_region&city=my_city`. It's certainly no better for direct SEO... search engines can perfectly understand query strings and with having the "name" they can perhaps understand the relationship between values better? However, since these URLs are the result of a "search form", do you want search engines to index (or even crawl) them? Ordinarily, internal search results should not be indexed by search engines. YMMV.

Comment: @narseoh And with regards to UX... these would seem to be dynamic search queries(?), rather than ordinary links to your pages. And if they are not to be indexed, then the impact on UX may not be significant. Again, YMMV. :)

Comment: Hi MrWhite, in this specific case the search form generated pages are important for SEO (there is a limited number of pages, a lot, but a limited number) so I need to index and optimize them, I saw a example of a website that implemented this url format but I still can't do it
I mean this format: cardiology/region/city | cardiology/region | cardiology/ (for now I have set up your solution (s-cardiology/r-region/c-city)